# dojox/mobile/_StoreMixin label and children properties

Tags: javascript, dojo

dojox/mobile/_StoreMixin has 2 properies that I'm curious about:

```
// labelProperty: String
// A property name (a property in the dojo/store item) that specifies that item's label.
labelProperty: "label"

// childrenProperty: String
// A property name (a property in the dojo/store item) that specifies that item's children.
childrenProperty: "children",
```

I'm not quite sure how I can **reuse** **or** **access** those properties in this scenario:

I have an array of objects A where each object A contains array of objects B, so something like this:

```
var data = [{
    id: "1",
    content: "some info",
    items: [
        {id:"a"},
        {id:"b"},
        {id:"c"},
        {id:"d"}
    ]
},{
    id: "2",
    content: "some info",
    items: [
        {id:"e"},
        {id:"f"},
        {id:"g"},
        {id:"h"}
    ]
},{
    id: "3",
    content: "some info",
    items: [
        {id:"i"},
        {id:"j"},
        {id:"k"},
        {id:"l"}
    ]
},{
    id: "4",
    content: "some info",
    items: [
        {id:"m"},
        {id:"n"},
        {id:"o"},
        {id:"p"}
    ]
},];
```

I put that data inside dojo/store/Memory that is Observable (via dojo/store/Observable).

Now I have a widget called W.js that has a dojox/mobile/_StoreMixin mixin, and I have store set to the Memory store with data above.

Would you have any examples of what I can do with labelProperty or childrenProperty? For example can I set childrenProperty to point to "items" (ie array of objects B) and then do something with it? I've searched for couple of examples but couldn't really find anything specific.

What I would like to do is **maybe** have labelProperty set to "content" property so I can print it out and childrenProperty set to "items" so I can print them out also (as previously mentioned).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a quick example below.  It is a simple Widget that extends the dojox/mobile/_StoreMixin to make it store aware.  I did not implement the onUpdate, onDelete, onAdd, but left some comments there for what they can be use for.  The usage of the labelProperty and childrenProperty can be referenced in the onComplete method.

My example makes use of the dijit/_Widget and dijit/_TemplatedMixin to make this a standard dojo Widget with added templating support.  You can probably go without the templating support.  NOTE: I did not test this widget, but it should give you an idea of how to use these two fields.

```
define([
    "dojo/_base/declare",
    "dojo/_base/array",
    "dojo/_base/lang",
    "dojo/dom-construct",
    "dijit/_Widget",
    "dijit/_TemplatedMixin",
    "dojox/mobile/_StoreMixin"
], function(
    delare,
    array,
    lang,
    domConstruct,
    _Widget,
    _TemplateMixin,
    _StoreMixin
) {

return declare("custom.W", _StoreMixin, {
    templateString: "<div data-dojo-attach-point='containerNode'></div>",

    labelProperty: 'content',
    childrenProperty: 'items',

    onComplete: function(items) {
        // loop through all the items and create individual div to display them
        array.forEach(items, lang.hitch(this, function(item) {
            // create the main div to show the label
            var labelNode = domConstruct.create('div', {
                // use the labelProperty here to pull the correct label property defined
                innerHTML: item[this.labelProperty]
            }, this.containerNode);

            // create an unorder list of all the items displaying its id
            var ulNode = domConstruct.create('ul', {}, labelNode);
            // use the childrenProperty here to find if this item has any children
            if(lang.isArray(item[this.childrenProperty])) {
                array.forEach(item[this.childrenProperty], lang.hitch(function(child) {
                    domConstruct.create('li', {
                        innerHTML: id
                    }, ulNode);
                }, this));
            }
        }));
    },

    onUpdate: function(item, insertedInto) {
        // locate the corresponding labelNode for this item and update the label

        // locate the corresponding ulNode for this item and add/remove any li that no longer exists in the children property
    },

    onDelete: function(item, removedFrom) {
        // locate the corresponding labelNode for this item and delete it

        // locate the corresponding ulNode for this item and delete it along with any of its children
    },

    onAdd: function(item, insertedInto) {
        // locate the labelNode at the given insertedInto index and add a new labelNode with the label for this item

        // create an unorder list of all the items displaying its id
    }
});

});
```